# CRM Database Design for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Ok, I have built a custom CRM web app for a client using PHP and MySQL. The app seems to work really well for them and so I have decided to create a commercial version open to the public.

The basic idea of it is that it takes the data captured from a website and then populates the database with that. At the moment there is simply and insert statement on the front end of the website.

The thing is, I want people to be able to sign up to the service, create an account and customise it themselves to suit their needs. My idea is that once they sign up they would be provided with a form action that submitted to their account when installed on their page.

Regarding tables in the database etc, currently there is simply a customers table as there is only one website using it. If people being to sign up and use the service, do i create a new table for every account? This might be right but it seems a bit silly to me. Or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: Go with single table unless you **know** you have to create multiple. Should there be problems, you'll learn and you'll know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it's better to add a `customer_id` column, and add a `WHERE customer_id=12345` clause to all your MySQL queries. Having a separate table per customer is certainly possible, but it may not scale as nicely.

Comment: Thanks. So you suggest a generic 'data' table that could hold everybody's form data?

Comment: Initially, yes. If you become the next Facebook you'd want to start sharding, but it certainly doesn't make sense to start off that way.

Comment: haha Well, who knows? What is sharding?

Comment: I provide this link with the strong caveat of **you almost certainly do not need to worry about this right now, and probably not ever**. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)

Comment: Ok. I doubt this app would ever get that big but its always good to know whats available. Thanks